# Need to implement client-server applications in different language that can communicate with each other

Tags: sockets, network-programming

I want to build a client and server application using **Socket programming** that can chat but the client and server has to be implemented in different languages.
I want to use C# and Java for that purpose. I want to know if its possible and if it is How?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and pretty easy, especially with C# and Java. Their implementation of sockets is pretty similar.

Few things to watch for:

1. Make sure you are serializing integers in network order. If I remember correctly Java and .NET put bytes on the wire in a different order. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123918/how-can-one-simplify-network-byte-order-conversion-from-a-binaryreader) for some guidance.
2. Make sure you are encoding/decoding your strings consistently, like using Unicode on both sides.
3. Don't try using `unsigned` integer types, Java only supports signed types (I'm sure there are libraries to deal with it if necessary).
4. I don't know how compatible `float` and `double` serializations are on both sides, so if you need it do some more investigation.

Good luck and have fun!