# Casting UInt32 to Int32: Different compiler results

Tags: c#, casting, uint, explicit-conversion

I was reading [How can one simplify network byte-order conversion from a BinaryReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123918/how-can-one-simplify-network-byte-order-conversion-from-a-binaryreader) and the initial code in the question made me think about the capabilities of the explicit cast between `UInt32` and `Int32`.  My main concern is with values greater than `Int32.MaxValue` or less than `0`.

These casts should be equivalent, but one works and the other causes an error:

```
public static void TestConverstion()
{
    // runs just fine, CastBack == aUInt
    UInt32 aUInt = UInt32.MaxValue; // 4294967295
    Int32 anInt = (Int32)aUInt; // -1
    UInt32 castBack = (UInt32)aUInt; // 4294967295

    // Build Error: Constant value '4294967295' cannot be converted to a 'int' (use 'unchecked' syntax to override) 
    UInt32 oneLineCastBack = (UInt32)(Int32)UInt32.MaxValue;
}
```

Why is one valid and not the other?

Where is the behavior of this cast documented?  The best documentation I could find was [Explicit Numeric Conversions Table (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which acknowledges that there is an explicit cast, but warns that explicit casts "may cause loss of precision or result in throwing exceptions".  Experimentation says that no exception is thrown, nor is precision lost.

[UInt32 Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint32%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) suggests that since `UInt32` is not part of the [Common Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that you should just use an `Int64` and waste half the bits when you need to represent a value above `Int32.MaxValue` but below `UInt32.MaxValue`.

Comment: Where's it documented?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2xf6xbyc.aspx , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288039.aspx . MSDN can answer pretty much any question about the basic stuff.

Comment: It is very clear that 1st one is a `variable` so compiler has no guess what could have happen where as 2nd one is `Constant` so compiler knows the range and complaint you as error.

Comment: Is Convert.ToInt32(uint) the same operation as (Int32)(uint)?

Comment: But why does the compiler complain at all if it is a valid runtime operation?

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(uint) is a different operation from (Int32)(uint).  The first throws an exception (rather expected) and the second seems to convert just fine based on the bit representation of the value.  (This is the behavior in C++, but I rather expected an exception in C#).

Comment: It is `unchecked` context wrap your code in `checked context` and try it will throw `OverflowException`

Comment: `unchecked{Int32 uncheckedInt = Convert.ToInt32(UInt32.MaxValue);}` still throws an exception.  ToInt32 documentation is not the explicit cast documentation.

Comment: Even when the explicit cast is put in an `checked` block, it has a different message in the `OverflowException` than `ToInt32`.  `System.OverflowException was unhandled
  Message=Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
  Source=Examples` vs. `System.OverflowException was unhandled
  Message=Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
  Source=mscorlib`

Answer (score 2):

The way you have the code laid out, you are simply dealing with the compiler's ability to determine the potential outcome.  Nothing really changes.  As the error message suggests to you, you could do this and arrive at the exact same result:

```
unchecked { UInt32 oneLineCastBack = (UInt32)(Int32)UInt32.MaxValue; }
```

The only difference between the two examples you give is that the second one is a *direct cast* of the `const` value to `Int32` which the compiler can immediately recognize as an error.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8(v=vs.71).aspx "If neither checked nor unchecked is used, a constant expression uses the default overflow checking at compile time, which is checked. Otherwise, if the expression is non-constant, the run-time overflow checking depends on other factors such as compiler options and environment configuration." - So the value becomes a non-constant after being assigned to a variable, the language that describes what happens next is vague.

Comment: I'm with you there, it is vague.  But rightly so, there's no statement about environment that makes sense, and compiler options?  You could weed through the list, but...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy.aspx

Comment: This might be the right compiler option: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz.aspx It metions cases of truncation, but does not mention cases of different bit representation of the same number of bits.